# Saving current page in scope variable in xPages?

Tags: xpages

After my users complete a form, I want them to return to the page that they were on before completing / editing the form.   How can I save the current page in scope variable in xPages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the inbuilt previous page function?

select the button, go to events tab and create an onclick event, in the drop down choose openPage event. Inside there is an option of "previousPage" as the page to move to.

failing that if you have some custom use case, why not have a scope populate in the "beforePageLoad" event on an XPage and either hard code it or if in a custom control figure it out from the URL. you will have to leave it out of the form page or else run script everywhere there is a link / button moving to another page

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the previous page feature but I don't think that will work here.   What I want to be able to do is to take them to a page that says "Your request has been submitted. Click here to return to the main menu."   The link would then take them back to the "view" (xpage) that they were on prior to creating a request. I had already planned to use the on load event of the xpage but is there any way to programmaticly get the current page?  That way I can have one CC that is on all of the "view" pages that  would save the current page.

Comment: you can get the url by "context.getUrl()" then pull out the bit of the string after the last "/"

Answer (score 3):

Get the current location using: (xpagescheatsheet.com) Full Path Including page name
facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURI(), store that in a sessionScope variable, then use that value to redirect user as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code in the afterpageLoad event of the view:

```
sessionScope.put('webFrom',context.getUrl().getSiteRelativeAddress(context))
```

Add the below code to the onClick event of the link/button, which redirects the user:

```
var redirectToPage = sessionScope.get('webFrom')||'';
redirectToPage != ''? context.redirectToPage(redirectToPage):context.redirectToHome()
```