# Xpages: 'Go back to last page' breaks if there is a login form in between

Tags: xpages

Here is the scenario:

Page 1 is accessible to Anonymous users and has a link to Page 2, which has access control. When the user clicks on the button and is not logged in, he gets redirected to the $$LoginUserForm. As a result my simple-action 'Back' button (redirect to $$PreviousPage) is broken.

Is there anything I am missing, or must I do a solution where Page 1 notes where it is in a session variable, and the back button is coded to redirect to go back to Page 1?

I've seen these examples:

http://xcellerant.net/2013/03/15/return-to-last-view/

[Saving current page in scope variable in xPages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899016/saving-current-page-in-scope-variable-in-xpages)

I've tried the various

```
facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequeslURL|URI|getContextPath
```

but they are not storing the full url, only the bit before the parameters.

i.e.

```
http://albis/Development/Schulungen/Schulungen1_0/Schulungen_(1_0)_Dev.nsf/Kurs.xsp
```

and not

```
http://albis/Development/Schulungen/Schulungen1_0/Schulungen_(1_0)_Dev.nsf/Kurs.xsp?documentId=30760AABFD61BCC2C1257CCC0051B7A5&action=openDocument
```

Any pointers? Should I store the parameters separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full URL have a look at this: http://mardou.dyndns.org/Privat/osnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?documentId=C6D87172AE858572C1257B1000070CA6

(Watch the last code snippet there)

This value can be stored in a scope variable and then be used as value for a hidden field called "redirectto" that you have to define in your custom login page (with 2 other fields "username" and "password"). Domino will redirect you to that page defined in that hidden field.

Second option is to compute the scope value (with the full URL) in to the URL that redirects you to the login page, e.g.

```
/myNSF/myLoginPage.xsp?redirectto=http://redirectWhereYouWantGivenFromTheScopeVariable
```

Comment: That looks like an elegant solution, I'll try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to manage the page navigation in scoped variables when there is a single "back" location, i.e. page 1.  Also, when this is the case stay away from $$PreviousPage and $$HomePage as well.  For a one-option-navigation why not just hard code the location for the page open like follows?

```
<xp:button value="Back" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:openPage name="/XPage1.xsp"></xp:openPage>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Paul, but in this case I would be going back to a specific document (Kurs.xsp?documentId=30760AABFD61BCC2C1257CCC0051B7A5&action=openDocument).